# dynamic classes not getting generated. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create dynamic classe using `scss`. For some reason,the following code with scss does not work and the classes are not generated. As I try to see in browser developer console, class is not generated.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
$spacer: 1rem;
$sides: margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right;
$spacerMap: (0: 0, 1: 0.25, 2: 0.25, 3:1, 4: 1.5, 5:3);

@each $size, $approx in $spacerMap {
  $spacerApprox: ($spacer * $approx);
  .m-#{$size} {
    margin: $spacerApprox;
  };
  .p-#{size} {
    padding: $spacerApprox;
  };
  .ml-#{size} {
    margin-left: $spacerApprox;
  };
}
```

Comment: The problem does not seem to have to do with the code. If you test it here: https://www.sassmeister.com, you will see that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `$` with both `p` and `ml` classes. Changing, such that it looks like `.ml-#{$size}` instead of `.ml-#{size}` will fix the issue.